# creating a struct that behaves exactly like int

Tags: c#, struct

I want to create a struct that behaves exactly like int, but is not int. I am considering adding or removing some features of int in the future, so using int wouldn't work.

What is the easiest way?

If a struct could be inherited, it would be easy, but sadly, that is not the case.

Comment: All structures behave the same way so what exactly are you talking about that you want that you don't already have? `Int32` behaves like any other structure. If you're talking about native language support through native types like `int` for `Int32`, `long` for `Int64` and so on then that's obviously not possible, because that would require changing the language. Please be specific about the actual problem you're encountering, rather than just giving us a general idea about what you want to achieve.

Comment: My guess would be that you want to be able to use literal values of this type, as you can for `int` and the like. If so, that's what you should say. In that case, it's not possible because, as I said, that is a language feature and you can't change the language. As an example, VB has the native `Date` type that maps to the `DateTime` structure and VB has support for `Date` literals. C# has no equivalent native type so `DateTime` must be used like any other structure, with values constructed rather than using literals. You can define your type such that it supports implicit conversions though.

Comment: Go look at the source for `System.Int32`. Note that it stores the actual value in a native int (which, I believe, is now exposed in the language). Take the stuff you want to keep, don't take the stuff you don't. Add a full set of math operators. Add implicit conversion operators to and from Int32. Add a set of conversion operators similar to those Int32. When you finish, you'll find you have a type pretty darn close to Int32 (the implicit conversion operators give you most of the magic allowing things like `MyInt i = 123;`). I have no idea why you'd do this, but you should be able to get close

Comment: By the way, when you finish this exercise and you think "OK, that wasn't too bad" and decide to create a 4-bit `Nibl` numeric type and think it will be easy, please realize it won't. Since you custom 4-byte int uses a native int under the covers, `Arrays` of your type _just work_. But without a native 4-bit type, you'll never get _plain old arrays_ to work.  (This, by the way makes for an interesting interview question - it let's you see how a candidate handles an intractable problem)

Comment: Thank you everyone!
At the moment, copying the code from https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Int32.cs and renaming "Int32" seems to be sufficient for my purpose.

But I still believe it could be (and should be) easier because what I am trying to do is conceptually close to overriding ( getting a complete copy of the implementation of int and making some modifications to it).

Comment: I have seen suggestions for "non polymorphic inheritance". While I think that could be useful for some situations like this, it would really require a significant amount of thought and design effort for a fairly narrow use case. Keep in mind that that the language designers will focus on "most bang for the buck", not implement everything that could be useful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make something like behaves *exactly* like `int`, because `int` is a primitive that is often handled directly by the compiler. However: you can create a `readonly struct` with implicit conversion operators, and implement `INumber<YourType>`, which will ensure that you provide all the expected operators. Also: override `ToString()`, `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object)` (and implement `IEquatable<YourType>`, `IComparable` and `IComparable<YourType>`, but: they're part of `INumber<>`)